# Tuple as key in clojure.core.cache

Tags: caching, clojure

I am currently experimenting with [clojure.core.cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache) and now I have the problem that I want to store values based on tuples of keys and I do not know what the best/most idiomatic way to do this is.

I was considering storing one cache for every first key value, where I can look up the final result with the second key value, but this does seem very unefficient to me.

Another way would be to concat the keys since this would be unique aswell, but this again seems a bit hackey.

Maybe the problem is too "big" for caches and I should use redis or create a mirroring db, but I want to expire the values after some time, so this does not seem optimal either.

Basically I have keys like `(organization-id, user-id)`, and I want to retrieve values for them and store the results in a cache with some expiry time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a Clojure vector for the tuples?  Clojure vectors are immutable values, are equal to each other only when their lengths are equal, and all corresponding elements are equal to each other, and can be used as keys in a map.  I do not recall if core.cache uses maps internally to represent the contents of the cache, but whether or not it does, it should be able to use vectors as cache keys just fine.

Comment: I now use a dictionary, is this valid aswell?

Comment: If by a dictionary you mean what Clojure calls a map, then yes, Clojure maps with all immutable values for keys and values is itself immutable, and two such maps are only equal if they have the same set of keys, and every key has the same associated value in the two maps.